# Eclipse does not show associate with SonarQube option while associating the project at first time

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have installed Sonar plug-in for eclipse Kepler.
    Installed Sonar server and running it locally from localhost (localhost:9000)
    Tested the Server connection in Eclipse from
    Windows>Preferences>Sonar>Servers. Connection is successful.
    For my Project, ran the Maven goal for sonar (sonar:sonar). Build is successful. I am able to browse the results in localhost. (localhost:9000)

My issue is with Associating the project to Sonar. When i right click on my project > Configure ,but it does not show associate with sonarqube option.

Help me associate my project to Sonar in eclipse. Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: Which nature does your project have? IIRC, only Java (JDT), C/C++ (CDT) and Python (Pydev) projects can be associated (but maybe this has changed)

Comment: i have created maven project

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for one of my Java project and I figured out that no facets were selected.

When I selected java in facets, I got "associate with SonarQube" option.
Open project properties by rightClick on projects->Properties
Select Project Facets and check whether any option is selected or not. If not selected, select facet according to your project then you should be able to see "associate with SonarQube".

Answer (score 0):

I did the below:

Project >> Properties >> SonarLint
and then click Bind this Eclipse project to a SonarQubeProject

Make sure the mapping is complete -> Eclipse Project to SonarQube project

Use Autobind selected projects button option

Finish